# How to write scripts to create new participants and assets in hyperledger composer?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I am trying to create new participants and assets in hyperledger composer by writing scripts. Please help me to do that. If it is not possible please let me understand the reason.Please provide the sample code snippet also.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick background, Participants and Assets are the "resources" that you model using [Composer Modeling Language](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/v0.19/reference/cto_language.html). The other resources are Transactions and Events.

For your use case, where you want to create scripts to add these resources, you'll need to use [transaction processor functions](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/v0.19/reference/js_scripts). In these functions, you'll utilize the [registry](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/v0.19/api/client-participantregistry) and [factory](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/v0.19/api/runtime-factory) to create participants and assets.  Also, remember that before creating a transaction processor function, you'll first need to create a Transaction resource.

A sample code below:

Say we have a participant *User*. And to create this participant, we use transaction *CreateUser*. So your model file will be:

```
namespace org.network.participants

participant User identified by userId {
  o String userId
  o String name
  o String email
}

transaction CreateUser {
  o User userDetails
}
```

And your script file will be:

```
/**
 * 
 * @param {org.network.participants.CreateUser} transactionRequest 
 * @transaction
 */
async function createUser(transactionRequest) {

    try {
        let userDetails = transactionRequest.userDetails;
        let userRegistry = await getParticipantRegistry('org.network.participants.User');
        let factory = await getFactory();
        let user = await factory.newResource('org.network.participants', 'User', userDetails.userId);

        user.name = userDetails.name;
        user.email = userDetails.email;

        return userRegistry.add(user);
    } catch(exception) {
        throw new Error(exception);
    }
}
```

You can refer to the [official composer documentation](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/v0.19/introduction/introduction) for further reference.

Comment: Hi Mrudav, I am very new to blockchain and hyperledger. Can you please help me understand the architecture of hyper ledger block chain.

Comment: Sure Murugesan. You could start with https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/. Here, you can start reading about the architecture, the flow and the components involved in the entire ecosystem. Also, if you feel stuck at any point in time, you could post your questions on the fabric channel https://chat.hyperledger.org/channel/fabric. The community is quite helpful. Also, you can ping over there if needed.